# Creating A Video from Screen Captured Images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to create a video of an application that captures screen shot at a defined frame rate. Everything is actually working fine only that the specified frame rate for the screen capture seems not respected by the function "renderInContext:" on both iPad 3 and iPad 2. I understand that because of the size of the screen considering also the retina display, renderInContext: performs slower than on an iPhone or an iPod.

The thing is on an iPad 3, if I set capture rate at 10 frames per second, the capture actually happens at 2 frames per second, which means I not able to capture 8 frames making the rendered video very jumpy and un smooth. On iPad 2 I was able to have as much as 6 frames per second which is bearable at most. However, iPad two will be faced out after some time and I'm assuming that iPad 3 will be the only device available on the market. So I guess iPad 3 would be where I should be refining my code.

I am not looking forward to have a screen capture rate of 10 fps or more on iPad 3, just to have at least 6 fps capture rate on iPad 3 would be fine. However its seems that renderInContext: in iPad 3 if I use the whole screen (which is 768X1024) its seems that its taking at least 800ms to finish rendering. Obviously I have renderInContext: running on a timer at a specific frame rate (for example 1/10 fps). I recon if some how the call to renderInContext: overlaps say for example it needs 800ms to finish but I have another call to renderInContext: after say 1/10FPS (which would be .0813) then in theory I am still capturing at rate. Storing the images in an array for later processing seems fine, but because of the large amount of memory allocated I would be receiving memory warning then a crash would happen.

In any case, my question is, is there any other way I can access the display buffer with using the method "renderInContext:". Or even, just writing the CVImageRef to a file with out having conversion from CVImageRef to UIImage before writing to a png? Or a method that will ensure that I can write the ImageRef processing at the same frame rate I have set, that way I know there will be little overlap and ensure memory is deallocated properly.